# Read from SQL Server without gridview to an ASP.NET C# page

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to create a webpage that will populate results from a SQL Server table. I know how to get it display using grid view as seen below, but now I want to format the layout of the rows information so that it is not in a traditional table view.

Can anyone help me or point me to some information on how to do this? I have tried looking at datareader, but I cannot find a good example without them going back an making a traditional table.

Currently my markup looks like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvContact" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Sender" HeaderText="From" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Receiver" HeaderText="To" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Message" HeaderText="Message" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Yeargroup" HeaderText="Year Group" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Start Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" Visible="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Expiry" HeaderText="Expiry Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" Visible="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="InkView" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("MessageID") %>' onClick="lnk_OnClick">View</asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

C# code-behind:

```
void updateGrid()
{
    if (sqlCon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        sqlCon.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("MessageViewAll", sqlCon);
    sqlDa.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    DataTable dTbl = new DataTable();
    sqlDa.Fill(dTbl);

    sqlCon.Close();

    gvContact.DataSource = dTbl;
    gvContact.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? It is not at all clear what you are having trouble with.

Comment: Trying to layout the data from a table in SQL like below instead of a traditional grid.  So basically Title will display above the message body and then loop through these messages.

Comment: So fill your data table like you are and loop through them writing out the HTML. You are talking about generating HTML in a loop which is the wrong way to do this in my opinion. Instead you should use the view templates in your grid.